# powershell if else statement not working for the else side

Tags: powershell, if-statement

In this simple script, the `if` statement works fine when the input file is present, but if the input file is not there it gives me this error and completes:

```
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\scripts\importfile.txt' because it does not exist.
At C:\Scripts\CLI_Localadmins.ps1:18 char:36
+     If (!($FileExists)) {$Computers = Get-Content -Path 'c:\scripts\importfile.txt'
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\scripts\importfile.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand*
```

this is the code I'm using:

```
#Check if import file exists.
$ChkFile = "c:\scripts\importfile.txt" 
$ValidPath = Test-Path $ChkFile -IsValid
If ($ValidPath -eq $True) {$Computers = Get-Content -Path    'c:\scripts\importfile.txt'
}     
Else {$Computers = Get-QADComputer -SizeLimit 0 | select name -ExpandProperty name
}
# Give feedback that something is actually going on
```

Comment: What is `$env:` in the variable assignment supposed to do?

Comment: Can you update the error message for the latest attempt?

Comment: Taylor Tvrdy Updated Error Message: Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\scripts\importfile.txt' because it does not exist. At C:\Scripts\CLI_Localadmins.ps1:17 char:42 + If ($ValidPath -eq $True) {$Computers = Get-Content -Path 'c:\scripts\importfil ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (C:\scripts\importfile.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand Processing ... Script completed for online systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your condition is that `Test-Path $ChkFile -IsValid` checks only if `$ChkFile` is a valid path, not if it actually exists. If you want to test for existence you need to remove `-IsValid`. Also, I'd recommend using `-LiteralPath`, because by default `Test-Path` treats the path as a regular expression, which causes problems when a path contains special characters like square brackets.

```
#Check if import file exists.
$ChkFile = "c:\scripts\importfile.txt" 
if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $ChkFile) {
  $Computers = Get-Content $ChkFile
} else {
  $Computers = Get-QADComputer -SizeLimit 0 | select -Expand name
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the IF statement as described by the error statement.. Try removing the exclamation point

Comment: ok now the else side works but the if side does not! if the file exists it is not getting the input from it.  It still pulls data from the else side of the statement.

Comment: Is the value of $FileExists different in each case?

Comment: Then the problem is in the way you are testing if the file exists

Comment: Changed the input checking to:
   #Check if import file exists.
$ChkFile = "c:\scripts\importfile.txt" 
$ValidPath = Test-Path $ChkFile -IsValid
 If ($ValidPath -eq $True) {$Computers = Get-Content -Path 'c:\scripts\importfile.txt'
}   
   Else {$Computers = Get-QADComputer -SizeLimit 0 | select name -ExpandProperty name
}
# Give feedback that something is actually going on



Still works with the input file but does not go to the else statement

Comment: @user2654059 Please don't post code in comments. As you can see it's practically unreadable. Update your question instead.

Comment: Edited code in original question to latest attempt.  The code runs fine if the import file is present but errors if it is not and does not run the else statement

Comment: Updated Error Message:
Get-Content : Cannot find path 'C:\scripts\importfile.txt' because it does not exist.
At C:\Scripts\CLI_Localadmins.ps1:17 char:42
+     If ($ValidPath -eq $True) {$Computers = Get-Content -Path 'c:\scripts\importfil ...
+                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\scripts\importfile.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
 

 Processing ...

 Script completed for online systems

Answer (score 0):

I found this [website](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2254.how-to-use-test-path-in-powershell-scripts.aspx) that may help. Here is a quote from the article, `"An important warning about using the -isValid switch...since there’s nothing syntactically wrong with the path. So Test-Path -isValid $profile will always return true."`I believe the -isValid switch is just checking the syntax of the path and making sure it is correct, it doesn't actually check if the path is there.

Try using split-path instead of -isValid like this

```
$ValidPath = Test-Path (split-path $ChkFile)
```